# Select where look like

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have that code which get data from API like this

```
[
    {
        "service": 1,
        "name": "Followers",
        "type": "Default",
        "category": "First Category",
        "rate": "0.90",
        "min": "50",
        "max": "10000"
    },
    {
        "service": 2,
        "name": "Comments",
        "type": "Custom Comments",
        "category": "Second Category",
        "rate": "8",
        "min": "10",
        "max": "1500"
    }
]
```

Then it insert the categories into the database table categories with column name title.

Then it insert the services into the services table, but before that it checks if the category name of the service looks like any of categories that inserted into the database to mark the service with category id.

```php
// Get categories
$category = array_column($services, "rate", "category");

// Foreach and Insert each one to the database
foreach($category as $key => $value){
    $data = array('title' => $key,'status' => 1, 'server' => $server_id);
    $this->db->insert('categories', $data);
}

// Add services
foreach($services as $item){
    $catData = $this->Setting->get_data('*', 'categories', 'WHERE title LIKE "'.$item['category'].'%"');

    if($catData){
        $catID = $catData->id;
    }else{
        $catID = 0;
    }
    $data = array(
        'title' => $item['name'],
        'description' => "",
        'category' => $catID,
        'price' => $item['rate'],
        'min' => $item['min'],
        'max' => $item['max'],
        'status' => 1,
        'server' => $server_id,
        'service_id' => $item['service']
    );

    $this->db->insert('services', $data);

}
```

I have a little problem, I can't use the operator = in the title as the API provider put some special characters at categories title like , so category with title ♛ PROMOTION (Cheap Services)  will be ♛ PROMOTION (Cheap Services) and stored at the database without the

so if I used the operator = it gonna fail, so that I wanna use the Like operator but I have another problem, the title that comes from the API contains  and the titled stored isn't

How can I make it select the category where the title look like it ?

Comment: Could you strip out these extra characters before trying to match them to the database?

Comment: It's a good idea and I thought about it but I faced a problem, now some categories contain these extra characters in the middle of it's name not the end, so it's stored like this ♛ PROMOTION [ A , without the remaining of the title. so I had to use Like one for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the category coming in from the API has more characters than the one on the database, you could reverse the like to say if the category on the database is part of the API string....

```
$catData = $this->Setting->get_data('*', 'categories', 
        'WHERE "'.$item['category'].'" LIKE  CONCAT("%",title,"%")');
```

Comment: Message: A non-numeric value encountered,  An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: DivisionByZeroError

Comment: Well, It's  working! but u missed a ) 'WHERE "'.$item['category'].'" LIKE  CONCAT("%",title,"%)"'); , Thanks!

Comment: I think I've corrected it - edit it if I'm still wrong.  Glad to be able to help anyway :)